# How to pass a std-functor in c++ and use it without knowing which one it is specifically

Tags: c++, stl, virtual, std, functor

I have something like a sort-algorithm here, and I want to pass it a functor, which provides the sorting criteria (std::binary_function). So it should call T.operator<() for example if std::less is given.

Problem is, the member function operator() is not virtual. So I need to know which type of object was given, to perform a dynamic cast which is not really nice.

Regards,

Dennis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Problem is, the member function operator() is not virtual. So I need to know which type of object was given, to perform a dynamic cast which is not really nice.

Why do you want to perform a dynamic cast? Normally you don’t need that. Just call the functor’s `operator()` just like you would call a normal function.

The whole point of a functor is that they behave like normal functions and you’re passing a template parameter into your algorithm (aren’t you?) to handle different functor (and function) types.

Of course, this whole thing is predicated on the fact that you *are* actually passing a template parameter into your function. `std::binary_function` is *not* suited as a virtual base class. It merely exists to define a few handy typedefs. Thus, your function declaration should look like this:

```
template <typename TBinaryFunction>
void your_algorithm(rest of parameters …, TBinaryFunction f);
```

Comment: i do not want to use dynamic_cast... but i also cant use operator() because in the local context, it's binary_function which has no operator() defined. afaik you have to overload it first to use it...

Comment: @Dennis: then you are misusing `binary_function`. As I said in my answer, it was never meant to act as a polymorphic base class. It merely defines a few useful typedefs, nothing more. You cannot meaningfully pass a `binary_function` into another function, this isn’t supposed to work.

Comment: ok thx.may you povide an example? (link?)  i intended to use binary_function as an unspecified superclass so that every compare-functor from the STL can be used... i do not really understand how to use a template here.

Comment: @Dennis: you *must* use templates here, otherwise this cannot work. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.14 has an example function named `myCode` that takes a functor (they call it “functionoid”) as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you pass your functor as a template parameter, so to have *static polymorphism*?

Comment: Pretty sure that this particular use of templates is not static polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt Signal and Slots or you can use Boost.Function